# ASP.NET MVC3 TextBoxFor, EditorFor, ValidateFor not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rendering, editorfor

I've been racking my brain around this problem. I have a legacy application built around a WebSite in ASP.NET. I added the proper things to allow adding MVC to it and it mostly work correctly.

I have a razor view that has a form tag in it (encapsulated within a Html.BeginForm). I also created a custom template editor for string. The problem I'm having is that when I want to render a normal textbox, editorfor or ValidateFor, ValidationSummary no markup gets generated. My custom template is executed, but any normal HtmlHelper don't seem to work.

Here is my view (it's a partial view)

```
@model L1.Web.UI.Infrastructure.SectionWrapper<L1.Web.ViewModel.PersonInfoViewModel>

<div class="section">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
      <div class="pad_10" data-bind="with: sections['PersonInfo']">
         <div data-bind="with: data">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <table class="full-table form-horizontal">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="30%" class="dotted-border-right">
<!-- This kinda work -->
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SectionData.Data.LastName,       
                       "modelTemplateString",
                        new {SectionName = "PersonInfo"})
!-- This doesn't render anything -->
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SectionData.Data.LastName)
```

In my custom template, I'm rendering plain HTML, which works. When I do an EditorFor in my custom template, it partly works. I don't see any of the validation attributes being generated.  ValidateFor, or ValidationMessageFor in my custom template doesn't generate any markup either.  Here is the code in my custom template (which resides in /Shared/EditorTemplates)

```
@inherits WebViewPage<string>

<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="@String.Format("input{0}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)" data-bind="localized: {resourceId: '@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName', resourceStore: $root}"></label>
<div class="controls">
    <input id="@String.Format("input{0}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)" class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="visible: $root.sectionDefinitions['@ViewData["SectionName"]'].isEditing, value: @ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName"/>
    <a class="edit-link" data-bind="visible: $root.sectionDefinitions['@ViewData["SectionName"]'].isInReadMode">
        <strong data-bind="text: @ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName"></strong>
    </a>
    @{ Html.ValidateFor(m => m); }
</div>
```

I also tried to remove my custom template from the project completely, thinking that it was always used, even when not specifying a custom template name in EditorFor. This didn't make a difference. It looks like that my project is partly unable to render any HtmlHelpers.

I also checked that ViewContext.FormContext wasn't null after the form tag is created and that part seems fine.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are the full file names for your editor templates in the /Shared/EditorTemplates folder?

The @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SectionData.Data.LastName) will probably be calling String.cshtml and your other one should be called modelTemplateString.cshtml

you will also want to make sure that the @model String tag is at the top of your editor templates

from what I can see your template isnt acutally using the model data that you are sending to it, its just using the ViewData object.

Comment: The full name is modelTemplateString.cshtml.  The problem is not that my custom template is not working. It is actually rendering it. What is not working is the default templates from MVC are not rendering any markup.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your LastName field is just a base String object?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What is neat is that even though it is a string, when I get in my custom template, I can still get the proper ModelMetadata from it (in the context of the model the property pertains to). What is not neat is that I'm unable to use the ValidateFor and EditorFor

Comment: Well, I found my problem... and I feel a little stupid about it. I had a missing key in my web.config to make the code generate any markup. Don't forget to add the following:     <add key ="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>